# Parsing Jenkins xml result with XStream

Tags: jenkins, xstream, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to parse lint-result.xml produced by Jenkins. I created stand-alone project that takes lint result file and parse it with XStream 1.4.1 (version that is currently used by Jenkins from what I seen in documentation) this works absolutely fine. However when I move code to Jenkins plugin (it is post-build plugin) I'm getting following error

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: com.peter.android_lint.parser.LintIssues : com.peter.android_lint.parser.LintIssues
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:68)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:71)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:86)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:96)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:56)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.HierarchicalStreams.readClassType(HierarchicalStreams.java:29)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:136)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:33)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:926)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:912)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:864)
    at com.peter.android_lint.parser.LintParser.parse(LintParser.java:25)
    at com.peter.ReportPublisher.findFiles(ReportPublisher.java:61)
    at com.peter.ReportPublisher.perform(ReportPublisher.java:48)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:36)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:814)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:786)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:733)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1592)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:237)
```

Parser class

```
public class LintParser {

private File lintResult;

public void parse(String fileName) {
    lintResult = new File(fileName);
    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.alias("issues", LintIssues.class);
    xstream.alias("issue", LintIssue.class);
    xstream.alias("location", Location.class);
    //xstream.processAnnotations(new Class[]{LintIssues.class, LintIssue.class, Location.class});
    LintIssues lintIssues = null;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(lintResult);
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        lintIssues = (LintIssues) xstream.fromXML(bis);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    List<LintIssue> issueList = lintIssues.getIssueList();
    for (LintIssue issue : issueList) {
        printIssue(issue);
    }
    if(bis != null){
        try{
            bis.close();
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void printIssue(LintIssue issue) {
    System.out.println("ID= " + issue.getId() + " , severity= " + issue.getSeverity() + " , priority= " + issue.getPriority());
    for (Location location : issue.getLocations()) {
        printLocation(location);
    }
}

private void printLocation(Location location) {
    System.out.println("\t Location file=" + location.getFilename());
}
}
```

LintIssues class

```
//@XStreamAlias("issues")
public class LintIssues {
  @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "issue")
  private List<LintIssue> issueList = new ArrayList<LintIssue>();

  public LintIssues(List<LintIssue> issueList) {
    this.issueList = issueList;
  }

  public List<LintIssue> getIssueList() {
    return issueList;
  }
}
```

LintIssue class

```
//@XStreamAlias("issue")
public class LintIssue {

@XStreamAlias("id")
@XStreamAsAttribute
private String id;
@XStreamAlias("severity")
@XStreamAsAttribute
private String severity;
@XStreamAlias("category")
@XStreamAsAttribute
private String category;
@XStreamAlias("priority")
@XStreamAsAttribute
private int priority;
@XStreamAlias("summary")
@XStreamAsAttribute
private String summary;
@XStreamAlias("explanation")
@XStreamAsAttribute
private String explanation;
@XStreamAlias("message")
@XStreamAsAttribute
private String message;
@XStreamAlias("errorLine1")
@XStreamAsAttribute
private String errorLine1;
@XStreamAlias("errorLine2")
@XStreamAsAttribute
private String errorLine2;
@XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "location")
private List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<Location>();

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getSeverity() {
    return severity;
}

public void setSeverity(String severity) {
    this.severity = severity;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public int getPriority() {
    return priority;
}

public void setPriority(int priority) {
    this.priority = priority;
}

public String getSummary() {
    return summary;
}

public void setSummary(String summary) {
    this.summary = summary;
}

public String getExplanation() {
    return explanation;
}

public void setExplanation(String explanation) {
    this.explanation = explanation;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public String getErrorLine1() {
    return errorLine1;
}

public void setErrorLine1(String errorLine1) {
    this.errorLine1 = errorLine1;
}

public String getErrorLine2() {
    return errorLine2;
}

public void setErrorLine2(String errorLine2) {
    this.errorLine2 = errorLine2;
}

public List<Location> getLocations() {
    return locations == null ? new ArrayList<Location>() : locations;
}

public void setLocations(List<Location> locations) {
    this.locations = locations;
}
}
```

Location class

```
//@XStreamAlias("location")
public class Location implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1128640353127613495L;

@XStreamAlias("file")
@XStreamAsAttribute
private String filename;
@XStreamAlias("line")
@XStreamAsAttribute
private int lineNumber;
@XStreamAlias("column")
@XStreamAsAttribute
private int column;

public String getFilename() {
    return filename;
}

public void setFilename(String filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
}

public int getLineNumber() {
    return lineNumber;
}

public void setLineNumber(int lineNumber) {
    this.lineNumber = lineNumber;
}

public int getColumn() {
    return column;
}

public void setColumn(int column) {
    this.column = column;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck getting a good answer to this question by participating in the [jenkinsci-dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jenkinsci-dev) mailing list.

Comment: Posted there too, so far silence only